# convexity of two linear spaces connected by convex nonlinear equality constraints

Tags: convexity, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

If there are two sets of linear constraints in different variables, **Ax <= b** with **x_l <= x <= x_u** and **Cy <= d** with **y_l <= y <= y_u**, and a set of equality constraints of a specific non-linear but convex form relating the two sets of variables **e^y - x = 0**, is the feasible space convex, and what is the proof behind the answer? The difficulty seems to me that the equality constraint would be equivalently formulated as **e^y - x <= 0** and **e^y - x >= 0**, which means that one of these inequalities would be convex and the other would be concave, which may somehow create concavities in the feasible space.

Comment: Of course it's not convex. Since if $e^y=x$ and $e^{y'}=x'$ then in general $e^{(y+y')/2}\neq (x+x')/2$. A more reasonable question would be if the its projection on $x$ or on $y$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant to indicate that the epigraph of the function e^y - x is a convex set, which is indicated by the Hessian of the function being positive semi-definite, which it is. I believe my question would have been better stated as you phrased it, regarding the convexity of its projection in either space. Any additional comments would be appreciated.